# How to setup privileged in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, db2

I am running a db2 container sample using this docker command.
Reference docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2)

```
docker run -itd --name mydb2 --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=Notallowed1! -e DBNAME=testdb ibmcom/db2
```

It is working.
If I remove the **--privileged=true** I will get below error.

[image: connection error]

So, **--privileged=true** is mandatory.

I tried add this to docker swarm as a service using this command.

```
docker service create --name db2luw_1 --privileged=true -p target=50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e 'DB2INST1_PASSWORD=Notallowed1!' -e DBNAME=testdb -d ibmcom/db2
```

But getting this error.

```
unknown flag: --privileged
See 'docker service create --help'.
```

How to run this container in docker swarm?
Removing the --privileged is creating the service but useless as we will get connection error.I tested that.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the answer by mac, swarm mode does not support privileged  mode still.

There is a hacky workaround though if you want to run privileged containers in swarm today: Just create an intermediate service which has access to the docker socket of the host, and then run a privileged container from there.

Something like the following should work:

```
 docker service create \
   --name mydb2-wrapper \
   --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock,ro \
   docker \
   docker run --name mydb2 --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=Notallowed1! -e DBNAME=testdb ibmcom/db2
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a service means you run your containers in swarm mode. See [How services work](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/services/) in Docker documentation on that.

Unfortunately privileged mode doesn't work in swarm mode. As you [see here](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/) the --privileged option isn't available when running `docker service create`